# Restrict Upload access to AWS S3 bucket from a certain domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku, strapi

Backend has been built using Strapi(3.1.3) and Media library has been installed for file upload. This app has been deployed on Heroku and since Heroku uses ephemeral filesystem the uploaded files does not persist upon re-deployment or restart of dynos.

To overcome this I am using "strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3" which stores the uploaded files in S3 bucket which is perfect.

Bucket Policy lets us restrict read access to a certain list of IP addresses, however how do i restrict access to upload files from a certain domain? Using IP address to give upload access is not possible because Heroku manages the dynos and it's IP address keeps changing

Can i use a domain name instead of IP address?

Any help would be great
Thanks

Comment: I am not so sure but check 'http referer' in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: I did go through these docs but nothing conclusive, Thanks